Optimize the scss nesting code with some general css code
Hi I am trying to style for some categories and subcategories. Here is the code
const listStyle = styled.div`
  --padding-value: 40px;
  .wrap {
    .listItem,
    .listItemCategory {
      padding-left: var(--padding-value) !important;
    }
    .wrap {
      .listItem,
      .listItemCategory {
        padding-left: calc(var(--padding-value) + 20px) !important;
      }
      .wrap {
        .listItem,
        .listItemCategory {
          padding-left: calc(var(--padding-value) + 40px) !important;
        }
      }
    }
`;

Anyway to optimize this in scss

You could extract the extra padding into its own custom property:
--padding-value: 40px;
.wrap {
  .listItem,
  .listItemCategory {
    padding-left: calc(var(--padding-value) + var(--padding-extra, 0)) !important;
  }
  .wrap {
     --padding-extra: 20px;
     .wrap {
       --padding-extra: 40px;
     }
  }
}

Note: Avoid using !important

Great! It works. Anyway to optimize this further to not repeat the wrap and padding extra value

You can probably simplify the nested extra padding with sass but I wouldn't bother if it only goes as deep as illustrated above - it's easier to understand as is

Yup I dont want to have the repetition so trying something like this now where the react component send padding as props  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78520711/react-component-which-renders-children-component-by-self-incrementing-the-paddin
