React component which renders children component by self incrementing the padding css value
Hi I am trying to achieve a usecase where in a react component sends some padding value to styled components by self incrementing it based on how nested it renders.
Lets say there is a List component which has to render a parent and child component with some extra padding so I have done the implementation like below, but I am not sure useeffect and usestate usage will be good here. There might be some side effects which iam afraid of.
Here is the list component
const Parent = ({ title, children }) => {
  const [padding, setPadding] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setPadding(padding + 20);
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <ListStyle padding={padding}>
      <div className="listItemCategory">{title}</div>
      <div className="wrap">
        <div className="listItem">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </ListStyle>
  );
};

Here is the codesandbox link EDIT HERE

you should probably use useLayoutEffect instead. Also your sandbox link is not working.

You can try accessing now

Let me check the usage of useLayout

you can implement it using useRef or useLayout also , if you want to avoid the side effects of useEffect / useState.

Okay . Any other way of finding the nesting and passing the padding value as props to styled components?

You can use useRef and useLayout , just useRef can also solve your problem.
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const Parent = ({ title, children, padding }) => {
  const nestedPadding = padding.current + 20;

  return (
    <ListStyle padding={nestedPadding}>
      <div className="listItemCategory">{title}</div>
      <div className="wrap">
        <div className="listItem">{children}</div>
      </div>
    </ListStyle>
  );
};

const List = () => {
  const padding = useRef(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    padding.current += 20;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Parent title="Parent" padding={padding} />
    </div>
  );
};

However , I believe useState would be a straight forward approach  , as useRef is typically used for accessing and modifying DOM elements or persistent values across renders, rather than managing component state.
